# Reset CPU fan speed

Tags: macos, mac, cpu, hardware

I use smcFanControl to control the CPU fan speed, and now wish to reset it so that MacOS automatically adjust the fan speed. Even after using the `Reset` option in smcFanControl, the CPU fan speed is still fixed to the last value.

How can I reset the CPU fan settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1**

Restarting the computer should reset the fans to the computers control. I would also recommend making sure its not in the startup applications so it doesn't turn on when you login, and possibly take control of your fans again.

**Solution #2**

If that doesn't work try doing a SMC reset, this will almost surely reset the fans to system control. Again with this one, I would recommend you make sure it isn't in your startup applications.

[How to reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295)

[Remove Start Up Application](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4052408?start=0&tstart=0)

**Recommendation**

If you still want to use software to control the fan I would recommend using [this software.](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/47386/macs-fan-control) I personally use it to monitor my computers temperature and to control the fans.

Comment: Thanks! SMC reset change the fan speed back to the minumum 2000 RPM, but it does not speed up even when the CPU is heating up (70-80C+). Macs fan control works great though